# OpenX White Labelling

Tags: php, openx

I'm sure I'm not the only one but I'm trying to remove some of the elements within OpenX's source code that mention OpenX so I can fully whitelabel it (which should be possible).

I can't for the life of me find where the mention is in code for the bannercode:

```
<!--/* OpenX Javascript Tag v2.8.1 */-->
```

It's driving me mad!

Anyone have any ideas?

Yours,
Chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the 2.8.1 version, it appears to be in `lib/OX/Extension/invocationTags` starting on line 238:

```
$buffer = '<!--/* '. $name .' '. $this->getName() . ' v' . OA_VERSION;
if (!empty($thirdpartyname)) {
    $buffer .= " (".$thirdpartyname.")";
}
$buffer .= " */-->\n\n";
```

Comment: Wow cool - no wonder I couldn't find it!
Any idea about the dropdown that mentions OpenX when you add a new banner?
Mine currently says html: OpenX Generic HTML Banner etc.

Thanks again!